# How to migrate data from 12c on-premise database to 18c atp database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I already have a database configured in atp. And the database version is 18c. I want to know the factors that I should consider before migrating data from 12c on-premise. Would also like to know how to do that? Is it doable using SQL developer? Do I need to take a back up before migrating data?

Answer (score 1):

Going from Oracle on-prem to ATP is best done via expdp/impdp. see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/load-data-data-pump.html#GUID-30DB1EEA-DB45-49EA-9E97-DF49A9968E24)

Comment: And yes you can use sqldeveloper https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/01/data-pump-your-on-premises-oracle-database-to-the-autonomous-cloud/